# Download speed spikes

Tags: performance, internet, download, isp, browsing

My download speeds drop to about 1 kbps then spike to between 200 kbps and 500 kbps then drop to about 1 kbps for about 5 seconds before it spikes again.

But if I surf the internet i get speeds between 700 kbps and 1 Mbps.

How can I get my downloads speeds consistent even if I do not get the full 700 kbps - 1 Mbps. 
How can I get it to maintain descant speeds?

Would this be a weird setting on my computer or a problem with my ISP?

Comment: Are you using a wireless or wired connection?

Comment: On a 3G or LTE connection the behaviour you're describing is entirely possible, not nice but possible. On a wired connection, that would be a malfunction in your or your ISPs hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Try a continuous ping and see if any packets are lost. From the command prompt type

```
Ping -t 8.8.8.8
```

Let it run for a few minutes.

Then do this again to your router (type ipconfig from the command prompt to get the gateway IP and then ping that for a few minutes in the same way.

[image]

Compare the results. This will inform you if the loss is between you and the router or between your router and the Google DNS (8.8.8.8)

Comment: what kind of results should i be seeing

the time for google is between 30-40ms but i saw a spike up to 350ms and the TTL=47

the time for my router is between 4-17ms and the TTL=64

Comment: How often are the spikes? And, are there any packet losses - how did it compare against pinging your router (default gateway)